# React, getting an error when a function is passed to the required attribute

Tags: validation, reactjs, input, required

Im trying to validate a fields required field, and I am passing a function to the required field. But the function doesn't seems to be called and right now im getting an error ("Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403") as well. Any idea to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.isReq.bind(this)
```

> Seems like your call was out of scope try this.

Comment: just call with `this.isReq()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :: binding operator like this

```
...
 <input 
  type='text'
  required={ ::this.isReq }
  requiredMessage="Enter the Validity End Period."
/>
...
```